# Understanding matrix transformation, image, and range of the transformation with an example

Tags: linear-algebra

Define a matrix transformation A as follows:

A = {{1, -1}, {2, -2}, {3, -3}};

Find the image of {1,3} under A and determine if {3,6,9} is in the range of the transformation.

*Source: Wolfram U Linear Algebra Course*

Seeking explanation of what it means A in the first place. Is it a set of three two dimensional vectors:

{1,-1}, {2,-2}, {3,-3}

The above 3 appear similar vectors in the sense of the same direction.
Or just 3 plain quantities that can be drawn in the graph by plotting {1,-1} for the first quantity. Similarly {2,-2} and {3,-3} for the second and third quantities?

It is only then perhaps I will be in a position to find the image of {1,3}.

Comment: Surely they intend $A$ to be the matrix $\begin{bmatrix}1&-1\\2&-2\\3&-3\end{bmatrix}$.  They wrote it that way because they don't have access to fancier typesetting at the time and wrote it as a sequence of rows.

Comment: "*Find the image of {1,3}*", they are asking you to perform the matrix arithmetic $\begin{bmatrix}1&-1\\2&-2\\3&-3\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1\\3\end{bmatrix}$.  Asking if {3,6,9} is in the range is asking if there exists a matrix $x$ such that $\begin{bmatrix}1&-1\\2&-2\\3&-3\end{bmatrix}x=\begin{bmatrix}3\\6\\9\end{bmatrix}$ (*equivalently whether or not $\begin{bmatrix}3\\6\\9\end{bmatrix}$ is a linear combination of the columns $\begin{bmatrix}1\\2\\3\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}-1\\-2\\-3\end{bmatrix}$.  It clearly is as it is simply three times the first column*)